# How to prevent saving a duplicate record based on a combobox selection

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am selecting a name from a combo box, I want access to detect if the name is already in the database and display msgbox if there is a duplicate.

I am using the following code, which is not working:

```
     If cboAdvisor.Value = [tblActive_coahing]![Advisor] Then
    MsgBox
    'do not save record
end if
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to replace your 'If' statement with a search of your table (is there other related code that you didn't show?)  What are the actual values of cboAdvisor.Value and [tblActive_coahing]![Advisor]?

You should obtain the value and then run a query against your table.